# convert base64 string into image

Tags: c#

I m trying to convert base64 string into image using below code

```
 byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

 // Convert byte[] to Image
 ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
 Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
```

but it is always giving me an error "parameter is not valid."

And also I want to store image in folder after conversion.

Comment: On what line do you get the error? Also, use `using` to prevent memory leaking.

Comment: Do you need it as an `Image` object in memory or is your only goal to store it on disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not Need

```
ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
```

and for your stream you can use:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes)
```

thats all i think.

Remember to use using blocks for your MemoryStream

```
Image image;
using (var ms= new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)))
{
  image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
}
```

To store your Image in FileSytem just use:

```
image.Save("c:\\myimage.bmp");
```

Comment: Maybe your Base64 string is not a valid base64 string ? Do you get the Exception on Convert.FromBase64String() ?

Comment: No. I m not getting any exception. but tell me can it happen when i will try to convert only half string?

Comment: @DipaliWagh you have to convert the full base64 string

Comment: Thanx @S.L. Its working now. but the image is blured

Comment: @DipaliWagh if you mean the saved Image ... try to find the right Format and use the Parameters for Image.Save() method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.drawing.image.save(v=vs.110).aspx ... have a look @ the overloads, but thats another question :)